# Unable to set document template path

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, pnp-powershell

I want to give document template path for site content type. i used the below code.

```
$SiteURL = ""
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$filePath = "/Template/DocumentTemplate.docx?"
$filename = "DocumentTemplate.docx"

$serverRelativeSiteUrl = "/sites/ClassicExp"
$ctName = "Any new Document"

# create the content type
$ct = Add-PnPContentType -Name $ctName -ContentTypeId 0x0101006604da7f262243448cb56226f4f30c79 -Group "Tester" -Description "No description available."

# upload the document template to the corresponding folder of the content type (site relative url)
$f = Add-PnPFile -Path $filePath -Folder "/_cts/$ctName"

# get the content type object
$ct = Get-PnPContentType -Identity $ctName

# set the document template in the content type to the uploaded file and update in the content database
$ct.DocumentTemplate = $filename
$ct.Update($true)
(Get-PnPContext).Load($ct)
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Error Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you can use the below PowerShell function to add a template to the content-type:

**How to add the template to Content-Type from the local system?**

```
function Set-SPODocumentTemplate($ctx, $ctname, $templateName, $templatePath){
  write-host "Getting $($ctname) content type information... " -NoNewline
  $contentTypes = $ctx.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes
  $folder = $ctx.Site.RootWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("_cts/$($ctname)")
  $ctx.Load($folder)
  $ctx.Load($contentTypes)
  try{
    $ctx.executeQuery()
    write-host " done." -ForegroundColor Green
  }
  catch{
    write-host "Error While Getting $($ctname) content type information $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
  }
  write-host "Uploading $($templateName) document template... " -NoNewline
  $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($templatePath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
  $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
  $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
  $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
  $FileCreationInfo.URL =  $templateName
  $Upload = $folder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)

  $contentType = $contentTypes | Where {$_.Name -eq $ctname}
  $ctx.Load($contentType)
  try{
    $ctx.executeQuery()
    write-host " done." -ForegroundColor Green
  }
  catch{
    write-host "Error While Uploading $($templateName) document template $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
  }
  write-host "Setting $($ctname) content type document template... " -NoNewline
  $contentType.DocumentTemplate = $templateName
  $contentType.Update($true)
  try{
    $ctx.executeQuery()
    write-host " done." -ForegroundColor Green
  }
  catch{
    write-host "Error While Setting $($ctname) content type document template $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
  }
}

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

$siteUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "Provide the URL"
$adminUsername = Read-Host -Prompt ("Provide user for {0}" -f $siteUrl)
$secureAdminPassword = Read-Host -Prompt ("Provide password for {0}" -f $adminUsername) -AsSecureString

$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($adminUsername, $secureAdminPassword) 
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

Set-SPODocumentTemplate $ctx "JS231SP Word Document" "template.docx" "C:\Templates\template.docx"
Set-SPODocumentTemplate $ctx "JS231SP Excel SpreadSheed" "template.xlsx" "C:\Templates\template.xlsx"
Set-SPODocumentTemplate $ctx "JS231SP PowerPoint Presentation" "template.pptx" "C:\Templates\template.pptx"
```

Reference:

[Setting the document template for a content type in SharePoint Online with PowerShell](https://js231sharepoint.com/2016/03/04/setting-the-document-template-for-a-content-in-sharepoint-online-with-powershell/)

Comment: this one works for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

You copy from this blog? https://olafd.wordpress.com/2018/07/30/create-sharepoint-content-type-with-document-template/

Change `$filePath`

from this >
 `$filePath = "/Template/DocumentTemplate.docx?"`

to location where DocumentTemplate.docx file is for ex. `$filePath = C:\Template\DocumentTemplate.docx`

Comment: still i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this looking to simply change the content type template to an existing file - without uploading a document. You can do this more simply

```
$MyContentType = get-pnpcontenttype -List "My Document Library" -Identity "My Content Type"
$MyContentType.DocumentTemplate = "New Template.docx"
$MyContentType.Update($False)  ### The reason for the false is that this bool is to update child objects. Since we're just setting a value it needs to be false "Update Method void Update(bool updateChildren)"
invoke-pnpquery
```